# compare array values with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array which looks like

```
positions = [{id: "pos1", name:"pos1"}, {id: "pos2", name:"pos2"}]
```

Then i have an object which has following structure

```
paritcipants = {pos1:[{salary:1000}],pos3:[{salary:1500}]}
```

So i want to check

- If every position item's id exist as a key in participant then keep it.
- If don't then make a new array under participants with that participant id.
- Remove other arrays if they don't match with any positions id.

Comment: Can you add an example aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function map for filtering.

```
const paritcipants = {pos1:[{salary:1000}],pos3:[{salary:1500}]};
const positions = [{id: "pos1", name:"pos1"}, {id: "pos2",name:"pos2"}];

positions.map(item => console.log(paritcipants[item.id]));
// pos1 => [{salary: 1000}]
// pos2 => undefined

Object.keys(paritcipants); // ["pos1", "pos3"]
```

More about map:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and perform the logic to add and remove the desired elements. I have added inline comments, please check and let me know:

```js
let positions = [{id: "pos1", name:"pos1"}, {id: "pos2", name:"pos2"}, {id: "pos4", name:"pos4"}]

let paritcipants = {pos1:[{salary:1000}],pos3:[{salary:1500}]};
debugger;
// Retrieve the keys of paritcipants ['pos1', 'pos3']
const paritcipantsKeys = Object.keys(paritcipants);
/* Iterate over positions and check if they exist in paritcipants
  if they are not in it then push it.
  else remove it from keys array so that you can know which are extra keys  in paritcipants
*/
for (const position of positions)  {
 if( paritcipantsKeys.indexOf(position.id) === -1) {
  paritcipants[position.id] = [{salary: 1000}];
 } else {
  paritcipantsKeys.splice(paritcipantsKeys.indexOf(position.id), 1)
 }
}

// Remove extra keys from paritcipants
for(const paritcipantsKey of paritcipantsKeys) {
 delete paritcipants[paritcipantsKey];
}

console.log(paritcipants);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly.  Here it's:

```js
const positions = [{id: "pos1", name:"pos1"}, {id: "pos2", name:"pos2"}];

const paritcipants = {pos1:[{salary:1000}],pos3:[{salary:1500}]}

let newParticipants = {};

for(const position of positions) {
  newParticipants[position.id] = paritcipants[position.id] || [];
}

console.log(newParticipants);

// newParticipants => {pos1:[{salary: 1000}],pos2: []}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code.

```js
var positions = [{id: "pos1", name:"pos1"}, {id: "pos2", name:"pos2"}];
var participants = {pos1:[{salary:1000}],pos3:[{salary:1500}]};
var mathcedkeys = true;
for(var i = 0; i < positions.length ; i++){
  var key = positions[i].id;
  if(!participants[key]){
    participants[key] = [{salary : 3000}];
  }  
}
for (var key in participants) {
    for(var i = 0; i < positions.length ; i++){
      if(key == positions[i].id){
        mathcedkeys = true;
        break;
      }
      else{
        mathcedkeys = false;
      }
    }
    if(!mathcedkeys)
    delete participants[key];
  }
console.log(participants);
```